# Pass function argument as data-toggle attribute?

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to write a function and call the function multiple times in order to pass a different data-toggle attribute every time as the arguement of the function but it doesn't seems to work? Is this possible?

Edit something like this:

```
var arguement1 ="something";

function test(param) {
    console.log('[data-toggle="param"]');
}

test(arguement1);
```

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? your non-existant function?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi, Can you be more explicit?

Comment: yeah sorry that was exactly what i was trying todo...now it works thx a lot!

Comment: @javabatz I moved my comment to an answer with a better explanation. Feel free to accept it if it helped you.

Comment: yeah thx a lot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the value of the function parameter `param` you need to use the variable correctly. Right now you are just treating it as a literal part of the string.

```
function test(param) {
    console.log('[data-toggle="' + param + '"]');
}
```

By closing the string with a single quote, just like it was started, we can now concatenate the value of the function argument `param` using the `+` operator. And then by using another `+` and starting a new string literal, with another single quote, we can continuing building the string.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wsyr5d9s/